# Android sending socket: What is the difference between these two methods for initializing a socket?

Tags: java, android, sockets

Method 1:

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.101");
int port = 18250;
Socket socket = new Socket(addr, port);
```

Method 2:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.101",18250);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same:

java source code:

```
public
class Socket {

...

    public Socket(String host, int port)
    throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
    this(host != null ? new InetSocketAddress(host, port) :
         new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(null), port),
         (SocketAddress) null, true);
    }


    public Socket(InetAddress address, int port) throws IOException {
    this(address != null ? new InetSocketAddress(address, port) : null, 
         (SocketAddress) null, true);
    }

...
}
```

Comment: The difference shows up in InetSocketAddress. The first constructor, InetSocketAddress(String, int) takes more time than the other one, InetSocketAddress(InetAddress, int) because it needs to verify that the String is a proper inet address. Source code for OpenJDK is available at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/net/InetSocketAddress.java#InetSocketAddress

Answer (score 0):

For a HelloWorld-style project there isn't much difference between them. In larger projects there can be some advantages in using method 1. If you already have a InetAddress object then by using the Socket(InetAddress, int) constructor avoids having the Socket-class check whether the string is a proper internet address.